# How to specify class on a JSX node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined a class name for the table below (as part of JSX).
`<table class="table">`

However once its displayed the class is not set on the table:

```xml
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
       render: function(){
           return (
               <table class="table">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Name</th>
                           <th>Address</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>...</tbody>
               </table>
           );
       }
    });
```

Instead the table shows as `<table data-reactid=".0.1.0.0">...</table>` in Chrome -> inspect element.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ReactJS uses the attribute `className` to avoid the use of a JavaScript reserved word.

```
<table className="table">
```

Comment: As the [questioner here mentions](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-I-have-to-use-className-instead-of-class-in-ReactJs-components-done-in-JSX), JSX is preprocessed, so reserved words aren't really a motivator. From "Ben Alpert, React core team": "*We certainly could have done it the other way around. I argued for that for a while... First, we tend to look at HTML properties (like `el.className = ...`) when possible, as opposed to attributes (like `el.setAttribute('class', ...)`).*" etc etc.